# CoreBluetooth delegate to async stream

Tags: swift, ios, async-await

I want to use async/await by `AsyncStream` for Bluetooth scanning. The CoreBluetooth is using the delegate pattern. The following code provides an adapter for using async await with CoreBluetooth.

Is there any potential problem with the following code?

Thanks

```
class BLEManager: NSObject {
    private var isPowerOnContinuation: CheckedContinuation<Bool, Never>?
    private var deviceContinuation: AsyncStream<ScanData>.Continuation?

    private var manager: CBCentralManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main)
    }

    func requestBluetoothUsage() async throws -> Bool {
        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            let ok = manager.authorization == .allowedAlways
            continuation.resume(returning: ok)
        }
    }

    func waitUntilReady() async throws -> Bool {
        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            isPowerOnContinuation = continuation
        }
    }

    func scanDataStream() -> AsyncStream<ScanData> {
        AsyncStream<ScanData> { continuation in
            self.deviceContinuation = continuation
        }
    }

    func stopScanning() {
        manager.stopScan()
    }

    func startScanning() {
        manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
    }
}


// MARK: - CBCentralManagerDelegate

extension BLEManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        isPowerOnContinuation?.resume(returning: central.state == .poweredOn)
        isPowerOnContinuation = nil
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        guard let continuation = deviceContinuation else {
            return
        }
        let scanData = ScanData(peripheral: peripheral, advertisementData: advertisementData, rssi: RSSI)
        continuation.yield(scanData)
    }
}
```

Use the `BLEManager`

```
private var scanTask: Task<Void, Never>?


scanTask = Task {
    do {
        if try await ble.waitUntilReady() {
            print("Bluetooth is on")
            ble.startScanning()
            let scanStream = ble.scanDataStream()

            for await dev in scanStream {
                self.devices.append(dev)
            }

        } else {
            print("power is off")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The `scanTask?.cancel()` will be called on event `onDisappear`.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I'm working on the same problem, would be nice to see how others are doing it, especially wrt. avoiding misusing the continuations.